# $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME''] in PHP-CGI ?

Tags: php, server-variables

I need variable `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']` in php-apache for PHP-CGI.

I want to use all variables of php-apache for php-cgi or a table compares variable between apache and cgi.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP-CGI the `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']` variable is always equal to `'php.cgi'`.

In order to have an equivalent of `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']`, you should use a combination of `__FILE__` and `basename()` (taken from [here](http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?426101-SERVER-SCRIPT_NAME-For-PHP-CGI))

For a list of differences between PHP as an Apache module and PHP-CGI, look [here](http://histonesolutions.com/difference_between_php-cgi_and_php_as_an_apache_module).

It seems that `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']` is the only server variable (talking about `$_SERVER`) that behaves differently in the two environments.